# Can an Ethereum full node confirm ERC20 tokens?

Tags: erc-20

Sorry new to blockchain development, especially Ethereum based tokens.

So to confirm ethereum transaction you'll need a full node for ethereum.

But can the ethereum node also confirm transactions for tokens on the ethereum network. i.e. USDT, USDC, AVAx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't consider "confirming transactions" as an issue, it's not something you typically need to be even aware of. The node client does that automatically and it doesn't affect you much.

Token transactions are regular transactions, which get included in blocks by miners. Once a miner includes such transaction in his block and successfully mines the block, he broadcasts the block and other nodes notice that the transaction has now been mined, and consider it handled.

So it's the miners of the network who "confirm" transactions in that sense. Most nodes in the network do not mine, they just relay transactions and read data.

**Centralized exchange confirmations**

If you are talking about the "confirmations" counted in centralized exchanges, it's a bit different thing. That's not really a blockchain concept per se, but a thing invented by (probably) centralized exchanges.

In this context, the amount of confirmations refers to the amount of blocks on top of the block we're interested in. So if the transfer is in block 10 and the blockchain is currently at block 15, then there are 5 confirmations. The more of such confirmations there are, the more certain it is that the transaction won't be reverted anymore by chain reorganizations. Typically I guess exchanges require something like 20 confirmations with Ethereum.

In theory a transaction is never 100% certain that it won't get reverted. In theory anything after block number 0 may get reverted still, but the chances for that to happen are trivially small.

Comment: Hey Lauri thanks for the answer. I'm trying to make a system that is similar to an exchange. So I need to confirm that a wallet has actaully received coins/tokens/funds. Is there a different way to confirm this?

Comment: Added info about the 'confirmations' seen by exchanges.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the information. It's super helpful. I'd like to accept it but I'm still not fully certain on the original question I asked. i.e. if coins that are on the ethereum block chain can be read by an ethereum node. i.e. avax or usdc or usdt

Comment: All nodes can read all transactions. So yes they can also "read the coins". The coins (or actually tokens) simply exist in the form of transactions.